# Capturing errors on Stripe source creation

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm running the following code, which is failing

```
stripe_card_response = customer.sources.create(source=source)
```

The response that I get back is as follows:

```
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stripe/stripe_object.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(*err.args)
AttributeError: sources
```

Within my python code, I would I capture that error associated with this failure so that I can print it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be using an older syntax that is no longer supported. To attach a source to a Customer you'd do:

```
customer = stripe.Customer.modify(customer.id, source=source)
```

Comment: Stripe indicates that .create is still valid https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/create